# rendering a composite node?

Tags: compositing-nodes

I made a simple layout to blur the output AND checked if compositing is toggled in postprocessing, yet Render only outputs the basic render (I checked with the Composite node disconnected). What am I missing?

[image: layout]

Comment: is your image editor set to viewer node or render result?

Comment: Where do I set that?

Comment: Your image editor (where your render appears) either displays the result of the composite node or the viewer node of connected. This is displayed in the image editor where the image appears on render output.Manual link is [here](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/image/introduction.html#controls)

Comment: Thanks, I missed it because I had to scroll down the popup list. For other readers it's the field in the top middle of the render window.